# Optimization of equation parameter values such that largest distance between groups is created

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, plot, mathematical-optimization

For a particular gene scoring system I would like to set up a rudimentary plot such that new sample values that are entered immediately gravitate, based on multiple gene measurements, towards either a healthy or unhealthy group within the plot. Let's presume we have 5 people, each having 6 genes measured.

```
Import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[A, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 2, 2], [B, 1.5, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2], [C, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 2, 1.4], [D, 1.7, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4], [E, 1.6, 1.9, 1.8, 3, 2.5], [F, 2, 2.2, 1.9, 2, 2]]), columns=['Gene', 'Healthy 1', 'Healthy 2', 'Healthy 3', 'Unhealthy 1', 'Unhealthy 2'])
```

This creates the following table:

| Gene | Healthy 1 | Healthy 2 | Healthy 3 | Unhealthy 1 | Unhealthy 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.0 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| B | 1.5 | 1.0 | 1.4 | 1.3 | 1.2 |
| C | 1.0 | 1.2 | 1.6 | 2.0 | 1.4 |
| D | 1.7 | 1.5 | 1.5 | 1.5 | 1.4 |
| E | 1.6 | 1.9 | 1.8 | 3.0 | 2.5 |
| F | 2.0 | 2.2 | 1.9 | 2.0 | 2.0 |

The X and Y coordinates of each sample are then calculated based on adding the contribution of the genes together after multiplying it's parameter/weight * measured value. The first 4 genes contribute towards the Y value, whilst gene 5 and 6 determine the X value. wA - wF are the parameter/weights associated with their gene A-F counterpart.

```
wA = .15 
wB = .25
wC = .35
wD = .45
wE = .50
wF = .60

n=0

for n in range (5):

y1 = df.iat[0,n]
y2 = df.iat[1,n]
y3 = df.iat[2,n]
y4 = df.iat[3,n]

TrueY = wA*y1+wB*y2+wC*y3+wD*y4

x1 = df.iat[4,n]
x2 = df.iat[5,n]

TrueX = (wE*x1+wF*x2)

result = (TrueX, TrueY)

n += 1

label = f"({TrueX},{TrueY})"

plt.scatter(TrueX, TrueY, alpha=0.5)
plt.annotate(label, (TrueX,TrueY), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0,10), ha='center')
```

We thus calculate all the coordinates and plot them

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H34m.png)

What I would now like to do is find out how I can optimize the wA-wF parameter/weights such that the healthy samples are pushed towards the origin of the plot, let's say (0.0), whilst the unhealthy samples are pushed towards a reasonable opposite point, let's say (1,1). I've looked into K-means/SVM, but as a novice-coder/biochemist I was thoroughly overwhelmed and would appreciate any help available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) combined with your code. (Since your code contains some syntax and type errors, I had to make small corrections.)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1.2, 1.4, 2, 2],
                            [1.5, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2],
                            [1, 1.2, 1.6, 2, 1.4],
                            [1.7, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4],
                            [1.6, 1.9, 1.8, 3, 2.5],
                            [2, 2.2, 1.9, 2, 2]]),
                  columns=['Healthy 1', 'Healthy 2', 'Healthy 3', 'Unhealthy 1', 'Unhealthy 2'],
                  index=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']])

wA = .15
wB = .25
wC = .35
wD = .45
wE = .50
wF = .60

from scipy.optimize import minimize

# use your given weights as the initial guess
w0 = np.array([wA, wB, wC, wD, wE, wF])

# the objective function to be minimized
# - it computes the (square of) the samples' distances to (0,0) resp. (1,1)
def fun(w):
    weighted = df.values*w[:, None] # multiply all sample values by their weight
    y = sum(weighted[:4])           # compute all 5 "TrueY" coordinates
    x = sum(weighted[4:])           # compute all 5 "TrueX" coordinates
    y[3:] -= 1                      # adjust the "Unhealthy" y to the target (x,1)
    x[3:] -= 1                      # adjust the "Unhealthy" x to the target (1,y)
    return sum(x**2+y**2)           # return the sum of (squared) distances

res = minimize(fun, w0)
print(res)

# assign the optimized weights back to your parameters
wA, wB, wC, wD, wE, wF = res.x

# this is mostly your unchanged code
for n in range (5):

    y1 = df.iat[0,n]
    y2 = df.iat[1,n]
    y3 = df.iat[2,n]
    y4 = df.iat[3,n]

    TrueY = wA*y1+wB*y2+wC*y3+wD*y4

    x1 = df.iat[4,n]
    x2 = df.iat[5,n]

    TrueX = (wE*x1+wF*x2)

    result = (TrueX, TrueY)

    label = f"({TrueX:.3f},{TrueY:.3f})"

    plt.scatter(TrueX, TrueY, alpha=0.5)
    plt.annotate(label, (TrueX,TrueY), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0,10), ha='center')

plt.savefig("mygraph.png")
```

This yields the parameters `[ 1.21773653,  0.22185886, -0.39377451, -0.76513658,  0.86984207, -0.73166533]` as the solution array. Therewith we can see the healthy samples clustered around (0,0) and the unhealthy samples around (1,1):[image]

You may want to experiment with other optimization methods - see [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

Comment: Looks brilliant! One last question I had is regarding the following line:
y[3:] -= 1                    
x[3:] -= 1
For my actual data set I have 9 columns, with the last 4 being the 'Unhealthy' ones. Should I then change this to y[5:] and x[5:] to adjust accordingly such that the last 4 columns are now seen as the unhealthy samples?

Comment: Lastly, and again, my apologies for the incredibly silly question. But I'm currently also trying to change the annotation of each point in the scatterplot to correspond to the name in the column header, IE Healthy 1, Healthy 2 etc instead of the coordinates. Would you mind helping out? Again, many thanks for all the support it has been invaluable.

Comment: We just have to set `label = df.columns[n]` instead.